# Net6 C#, Linux vs Windows, different floating point calculations?

Tags: c#, linux, windows, .net-6.0

I am doing floating point calculation with doubles with C# under Net6 (runtime Net 6.0.2) on Windows (Windows Server 2019 Datacenter) and Linux (ubuntu 20.04), and I get different results.

I did this :

```
double a = 350668.75030235935;
double b = 5.484834659364377;
double result = a * (Math.Pow((1 + b / 100), 1.0 / 12.0) - 1);
byte[] aa = BitConverter.GetBytes(a);
byte[] bb = BitConverter.GetBytes(b);
byte[] rr = BitConverter.GetBytes(result);

Console.WriteLine("a * ((1 + b / 100)^(1 / 12) - 1)\n");
Console.WriteLine("a = " + a.ToString() + " (hexa = " + BitConverter.ToString(aa).Replace("-", "") + ")");
Console.WriteLine("b = " + b.ToString() + " (hexa = " + BitConverter.ToString(bb).Replace("-", "") + ")");
Console.WriteLine("result = " + result.ToString() + " (hexa = " + BitConverter.ToString(rr).Replace("-", "") + ")");
```

I compile with Windows and Linux with x64 target platform :
[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJcMr.png)

[Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JRpog.png)

I run them both with the command line on environments with the same runtime :
[Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/chme8.png)

[Linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1UCU.png)

And as you see, I get different results (I also put the hexadecimal representation so that there's no mistake it's the values, not the way they are converted to string).

This is highly unexpected. I didn't find anything on the subject (except about gcc, but Net6 doesn't use gcc, or does it ?).

Any solution to get the exact same results on both platforms ?

Comment: Many important changes were only made in .NET 7, https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/dotnet-7-generic-math/ So if I were you I would upgrade to .NET 7 and try again.

Comment: Is the OS the only thing which is different? Are both machines are running on the same CPU? _"but Net6 doesn't use gcc, or does it ?"_ - .NET runs inside specific environment - CLR which is written in C++ to my knowledge.

Comment: @LexLi, I installed it and sadly got the same results.

Comment: @GuruStron, I tested it on my laptop and different Azure VMs with different Intel processors for the same results.

So my guess is that the compiler they are using for the CLR is having different ways to handle some basic mathematical functions (like Power) on different platforms ... I don't think there's a solution :(

Comment: You will have to go deep into MSIL and their actual interpretation by the runtime (JIT or AOT) so as to learn what exactly are the CPU instructions sent for calculation and those can answer the differences. But, back to the very basic, floating point calculation is known to be inaccurate to a certain degree and people get used to that. If you want more accuracy, then you should use other data types or libraries.

Comment: As @LexLi wrote - floating arithmetic is not designed to be very precise, I can't say if the described behavior is expected or is a bug (submit an issue to the runtime github repo). If you need more prescision - try switching to decimals.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I know quite well about the limitations of double format, I just wasn't expecting the CLR to behave differently on same hardware/different platforms in that regard. Floating point calculations are hardware dependent/platform independent for the same compiled code, so for sure the final compiled code is different. 

In this article we have more details on that topic, and it looks like it's not bound to change : https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/42747

I'll still try to confirm that with Microsoft support nonetheless.